# Git reset --hard without losing history

Tags: git

I have the following situation:

```
A-B-C-D (master)
```

I want to undo all local changes from D and go from D to where everything was like in B, but i don't want to just go to B. I want the stage of B to be appended to the current history, so that i end up with:

```
A-B-C-D-B' (master)
```

So like reverting from D to B but with keeping this Reverting in the history.

When i do a reset `--hard` I lose my history from B to D and i end up with:

```
A-B (master)
```

I just want to append a point in history to the history and start working on this top point and this without creating new branches stashes etc. Like getting everything how it was in B and commiting it (with commit message: "reverted from B") on top.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: So... how does what you want differ from `git revert`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I revert a Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-do-i-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Comment: Reset doesn’t lose history. It will lose uncommitted changes, and move a branch pointer. You even get an unreachable commit via the ref log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `git revert` is exactly what you're looking for. It creates a new commit that reverts the changes of the given commits.

In your case, the following commands are all equivalent:

```
git revert HEAD~2..
git revert HEAD~1 HEAD
git revert <hash_of_C>..<hash_of_D>
git revert <hash_of_B>..
```

See [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) for more info.

Comment: `git revert B..` in this case.

Comment: @Amadan hmm doesn't that revert B too?

Comment: [Docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-Theememtwo-dotRangeNotation): "you can ask for commits that are reachable from `r2` excluding those that are reachable from `r1` by `^r1 r2` and it can be written as `r1..r2`." Thus, `B..` is all commits reachable from `HEAD` that are not reachable by `B` (i.e. it also excludes `B`).